# convert a report to pdf using itextsharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf-generation, itext

im trying to convert my site to pdf, my site is for reports, on one page you enter information and on the other page you get it by sessions, there are pictures in the site and css if it matters.

im trying to use itextsharp but its too complicated to me.

i try to use some of the examples here but none of them is exactly what i need so it doesnt work.
http://simpledotnetsolutions.wordpress.com/2012/04/08/itextsharp-few-c-examples/

can anyone explain to me what i need to do?

i also tried this code but it doesnt work, someone told me i need to use xmlworker but i didnt realy understand how (and if it will work)

```
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=TestPage.pdf");
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
this.Page.RenderControl(hw);
StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 100f, 0f);
HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
pdfDoc.Open();
htmlparser.Parse(sr);
pdfDoc.Close();
Response.Write(pdfDoc);
Response.End();
```

thank you

by the way im capable of paying for it if there is an easy solution that costs money.

Comment: Have you considered SSRS?  SSRS reports can be output as PDF.  Converting HTML rendered output to PDF is not going to be simple.  At the very least save the report in a more generic format that can be re-used to display as HTML or PDF.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Scryber](http://scryber.codeplex.com/), it's pay in commercial ussage, but you can use the free version (it adds a watermark on generated .pdf files) for prototyping.

A .pdf file structure and styles are configurable in .xml so it's quite easy and flexible.

Exaple of defining a structure

```
<data:ForEach select="rss/channel" datasource-id="BBCRss" >
         <Template>
           <pdf:Div style:class="heading" >
             <data:If test="string-length(image/url) &gt; 0" >
               <Template>
                 <pdf:Link action="Uri" file="{xpath:image/link}" new-window="true" alt="{xpath:image/title}" >
                   <Content>
                     <pdf:Image src="{xpath:image/url}" style:width="{xpath:image/width}" style:padding="10" />
                   </Content>
                 </pdf:Link>
               </Template>
             </data:If>
               <pdf:H1 style:class="red-text" text="{xpath:title}"></pdf:H1>
               <pdf:Label text="{xpath:description}" /><BR/>
               Date: <pdf:Label text="{xpath:lastBuildDate}" />
           </pdf:Div>

           <pdf:Div style:class="content" >            
             <data:ForEach select="item" >
               <Template>
                 <pdf:Div style:class="rss-item red-underline" >
                   <pdf:Div style:class="rss-item-data" >
                     <pdf:H2 style:class="red-text" text="{xpath:title}" ></pdf:H2>
                     <pdf:Label text="{xpath:description}" />
                   </pdf:Div>
                 </pdf:Div>

          </Template>
 </data:ForEach>
```

and style

```
<style:Style applied-type="pdf:Div" applied-class="content" >
   <style:Columns count="2" alley-width="20pt"/>
   <style:Font size="12pt" bold="false" italic="false"  />
 </style:Style>
```

[Here](http://scrybersamples.codeplex.com/) you'll find sample project and some explanation.
Moreover, Scryber is better documented than iTextSharp.